# How do I specify ANTLR AST node types?

Tags: python, antlr

I'd like to use ANTLR to produce an AST which I can walk manually (using hand-written visitor code instead of ANTLR's tree grammars.) Say I have the following grammar

```
expr    : term ( ( PLUS | MINUS )^  term )*;

term    : factor ( ( MULT | DIV )^ factor )* ;

factor  : NUMBER
```

I'd like both `expr` and `term` to produce AST nodes with type `BinaryExpression` if and only if there is an operator (plus, minus, times or divide) being matched, and to produce a plain `NUMBER` otherwise. I know I could append an action like `$type = "BINARYEXPRESSION"`, but that seems like a hack. Is there a better approach? Is using ANTLR to generate a parser for a manually-traversed tree a bad idea?

**Edit:**

I've tried

```
expr    : term ( ( PLUS<BinaryExpression> | MINUS<BinaryExpression> )^  term )*;
```

But a) this doesn't seem to have any effect at all (the nodes produced are still instances of CommonTree and CommonToken), and b) to save on repetition, I want this typing to be applied to the entire node constructed by a given rule, instead of applying the type to the child nodes of the current rule. I.e. I shouldn't have to put `<Identifier>` in every rule which has Identifiers as children.

Answer (score 0):

The typical syntax is [`Terminal<ASTNodeType>`](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction#Treeconstruction-heterogeneous) (click for reference), but since it appears you're using the Python target you'll have to verify this.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that syntax, but I can't seem to get it to suit my purpose. See edit for clarification.